# Run PowerShell script from Shortcut with %cd%

Tags: powershell, cmd, shortcut

I am trying to call a PowerShell script from a shortcut and transfer the current location as an argument.
I tried to use %cd% for the current location and made the following **shortcut target**:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "& 'C:\temp\CurrentLocation.ps1'" -location %cd%
```

The **PowerShell script** looks like this:

```
param(
    $location
)
Write-Host $location
```

But the **output** is always:

```
%cd%
```

Can somebody tell me what do I have to set to call the PowerShell script with the current location?

Thanks

**Edit:**
Using the Shortcut target command in a normal command prompt gives me exactly what I need. What is the difference?

Comment: `%cd%` handled specially by CMD, it is not an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$pwd` holds the current location. Is this what your meant?

Comment: I don't want to get the current location in the PowerShell script but call the PowerShell script with the current location of the Shortcut.

Comment: What about:
[environment]::GetFolderPath('cd')

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "& 'C:\temp\CurrentLocation.ps1'" -location %cd%
```

To this:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -file C:\temp\CurrentLocation.ps1 -location "%cd%"
```

Also, this could be an easier approach:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -command (get-location).Path
```

Comment: Thanks, your second approach did the trick, I think you meant C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -command "C:\temp\CurrentLocation.ps1" (get-location).Path. However your first command will give me the output: "%cd%", did it work for you?